# Trying to submit a form with jquery, ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know there are many questions like this, but none of them worked for me.

I have a form and that needs to be submitted without the page reloading, while this is happening I need a random number to be generated.

Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/9M4g2qNL

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
        <meta name="author" content="Tom Heek" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

        <title>Index</title>  
</head>

<body>

<?php

/**
* @author Tom Heek
* @copyright 2014
*/

   $max = '1000';
   $rand = rand(1,$max);
   echo $rand;

?>

<form action="" id="guess" method="POST">
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" />
<input type="submit" value="Bet" />
<p style="display: none;">Please enter a number between 1 and <?php echo $max; ?></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var t = false

$('input').focus(function () {
    var $this = $(this)

    t = setInterval(

    function () {
        if (($this.val() < 1 || $this.val() > 1000) && $this.val().length != 0) {
           if ($this.val() < 1) {
               $this.val(1)
           }

           if ($this.val() > 1000) {
               $this.val(1000)
           }
           $('p').fadeIn(1000, function () {
               $(this).fadeOut(1000)
           })
       }
   }, 50)
})

$('input').blur(function () {
   if (t != false) {
       window.clearInterval(t)
       t = false;
    }
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's going wrong with your code?

Comment: you tagged ajax  but you have not any ajax call?you need to use ajax

Comment: I have no idea how, I am completely new to Ajax, that is why I was searching for it, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Did you make your own researchs? Maybe [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) since you tagged jQuery

Comment: I did, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to post the form data using ajax. That can be done by adding something like this to the click event of your button

```
$('#BetButton').click(function () {
    var value = $('#BetInput').val();
    $.post("page.php", { bet: value }, function(result) {
      // handle result
    });
});
```

This example requires that you add the corresponding ids (`BetButton` and `BetInput`) to your inputs. In order for the form not to post you need to remove `action=""` and `method="POST"` from the form tag.